# How to implement a search queue

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in swift3.0 I am implementing a custom search box. I wish to know how can i make a search queue such that on text change in searchbox i need to perform search operation with new text and if there is an existing search operation going on cancel that. I also want to include threshold ontextchanged. So that search operation does not get fired very frequently

Comment: So whats problem with `UISearchController` ?? :/

Comment: @agent_stack I wish to create a custom UI like uber app.

Comment: So you wanted the textField where user can search location? Is am I right?

Comment: @agent_stack yes I want a textfield  where user can search location

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDAutocompletionTextfield

Comment: @agent_stack The autocomplete textfield helps. But I am also looking into mechanism of thresholding and single execution as mentioned

Comment: **I am also looking into mechanism of thresholding and single execution as mentioned** <- Didn't get you. Can you explain this?

Comment: @agent_stack I meant something like when user type words in the textbox it should be able to throttle the events and then call any API methods to get auto complete suggestion and if there was already a call going on for previous suggestion it should cancel that and start request for new suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somehow general, but let me tell you how I accomplished this in Swift 3 and AFNetworking (this assumes you wish to search for the data on the server).

I hold a reference of the networking manager in the properties of the view controller:

```
//The network requests manager. Stored here because this view controller extensively uses AFNetworking to perform live search updates when the input box changes.
var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
```

Afterwards, using UISearchController I check to see if there is any text entered in the search box at all and, if it is, I want to make sure there aren't any other ongoing AFNetworking tasks from now by closing any of them which are still running:

```
//Called when the something is typed in the search bar.
func updateSearchResults (for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if !SCString.isStringValid(searchController.searchBar.text) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        tableView.reloadData()
        return
    }
    data.searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!

    /**
        Highly important racing issue solution. We cancel any current request going on because we don't want to have the list updated after some time, when we already started another request for a new text. Example:

        - Request 1 started at 12:00:01
        - We clear the containers because Request 2 has to start
        - Request 2 started at 12:00:02
        - Request 1 finished at 12:00:04. We update the containers because data arrived
        - Request 2 finished at 12:00:05. We update the containers because data arrived
        - Now we have data from both 1 and 2, something really not desired.
     */
    manager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks) in
        dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    }

    /**
        Reloads the list view because we have to remove the last search results.
     */
    reloadListView()
}
```

In the end, I also check in the `failure` closure if the code of the error is not `NSURLErrorCancelled`. Because, if that happened, I don't display any error message or toast.

```
 //The operation might be cancelled by us on purpose. In this case, we don't want to interfere with the ongoing logic flow.
 if (operation?.error as! NSError).code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
    return
 }
 self.retrieveResultListFailureNetwork()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks this helps in terms of http request and response but i am actually looking into more generic were i can add any task and cancel it if a new task comes in.